# Throwing things and people as weapons, how would this work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am interested in my buffed out, enlarged character throwing objects and even people as weapons.  What are my options to do so?  The normal throwing rules don't appear to take strength or size into account when it logically seems like they should.

I'm interested in any existing Pathfinder rules on throwing people and nonweapon objects - how far I can throw them, what damage do they do (or take), et cetera.

Comment: All your bullet points with physics math would just derail the question.  I've edited it down to a concise question that I believe is answerable by those conversant with the Pathfinder rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Throwing As Usual**

Under "normal" circumstances, a creature can throw an [improvised thrown weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons).

> **Improvised Weapons**
>
> Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in combat. Because such objects are not designed for this use, any creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

This will take size into account automatically, as if you're of larger size you'd compare to weapons of larger size too.  So if you're throwing a rock about the size of a mace, if you're Medium it would do 1d8 damage but if you're Large it would do 2d6 damage (see Tiny and Large Weapon Damage [on the same page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons)).

Of course if you go too large you get fewer throws.

> **Thrown Weapons:** The wielder applies his Strength modifier to damage dealt by thrown weapons (except for splash weapons). It is possible to throw a weapon that isn't designed to be thrown (that is, a melee weapon that doesn't have a numeric entry in the Range column on Table: Weapons), and a character who does so takes a –4 penalty on the attack roll. Throwing a light or one-handed weapon is a standard action, while throwing a two-handed weapon is a full-round action. Regardless of the type of weapon, such an attack scores a threat only on a natural 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. Such a weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

Also, [range](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons).

> **Range:** Any attack at more than this distance is penalized for range. Beyond this range, the attack takes a cumulative –2 penalty for each full range increment (or fraction thereof) of distance to the target. For example, a dagger (with a range of 10 feet) thrown at a target that is 25 feet away would incur a –4 penalty. A thrown weapon has a maximum range of five range increments. A projectile weapon can shoot to 10 range increments.

This means your improvised thrown weapon can be thrown up to 50 feet (5 x the 10 foot range increment). Range isn't affected by size.  Max range isn't affected by strength but accurate range is; those strength bonuses offset the range increment penalties.

Of course weapon size is different than creature size, so the intent isn't that you can throw a Medium creature if you're Medium; even a Small creature is larger than two-handed Medium weapons. If you had a pixie buddy you might make a case to the GM that he's the same size and weight as something in the weapons list so the thrown improvised rules apply.

"But but physics?"  This is D&D, give it up or come up with your own creepy complex houserules like everyone did in the 1970s.

**Pumping It Up**

There are various rules options to allow you to throw larger items better, and especially to throw people.

The [Throw Anything feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final) dispenses with the -4 nonproficiency penalty for throwing improvised weapons/objects. Follow it up with Improvised Weapon Mastery for a damage increase. Obviously all the other available ranged feats apply as well; if you want more range, more damage, more attacks, what have you, the *Shot feats are applicable.

The [Raging Throw feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/raging-throw) lets you use rage points to throw people into other people or things and it has damage rules specific to the feat. As a barbarian, this is probably your go-to.

The [Ki Throw feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ki-throw-combat) (and its various improved and other addons) let you toss an opponent. Rules for hitting and damage they take are explained therein. A monk in the pirate game I GM has this, he used it to toss a clay golem off a ship last Sunday.

The [Awesome Blow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/awesome-blow) feat, if you can make the STR 25 and size large requirements, gets you the ability to whack people around all the time on top of your existing attacks. It has Improved and Mythic versions too. I wrote a [Brute prestige class](http://mxyzplk.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/brute-prestige-class.pdf) I used in a 3.5 game based on the concept of growing to size Large and then getting this, starting from rage growth like unto [Sláine's](http://www.2000adonline.com/books/slaine-the-grail-war.php) warp-spasm.

Comment: There is also the Raging Hurler rage power - It's similar to Raging Throw.

Comment: Creatures are not objects in the game system. So you cannot use a creature as an improvised object unless you have some special ability saying so.

Answer (score 0):

## As improvised weapons

I did a similar build, and when the DM asked I just said "I'm using the creature as an improvised weapon."

(My build was using an ogre tetori monk. I used the ogre quick at hand feat and buffed the strength to ridiculous levels. The tetori wrestler gives me huge grapple buffs and the ogre's strength and size advantage makes it fairly straightforward. I was basically playing as the Incredible Hulk.)

Answer (score 0):

## It Depends on what you mean by "Throwing"

### Throwing things as Weapons

This is the easiest part to answer. [As I said in an answer for this post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/damage-of-an-improvised-ranged-weapon/93179#93179), there is a size and weight limit to what you can throw; for example, a medium creature can use an item between 1-4 lbs and a quarter of their size as a *light weapon*, an item between 2-8 lbs and half their size as a *one-handed weapon*, or an item between 6-15 lbs and equal to their size as a *two-handed weapon*, due to how the *Core Rule Book* explains the three categories that each tree of weapons is sorted under (this also gives you a rough idea of how much damage your chair does). Furthermore, the weight of weapons are either doubled or halved for each difference in size category of the intended creature ([also, said in same post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/damage-of-an-improvised-ranged-weapon/93179#93179)); this means that the weight limits for improvisable weapons ALSO follow this rule **and** that if a weapon is a certain weight but is particularly thin or thick, it can have up to a -4 base penalty for use ([considering the dis-proportioned weapon rule as detailed in the middle of this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/)).

To get the most out of this, you want to get at least the **[Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final/)** Feat, to get rid of the inherent difficulty of throwing something as poorly aerodynamic as a stump 50ft AND still hurt someone. Speaking of which, you should also get the **[Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final/)** Feat to toss a number of objects in reach within the same turn and the **[Two-Handed Thrower](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-handed-thrower-combat/)** Feat just in case you can't find anything small enough to throw or need the extra 1.5 Strength Based Damage Bonus.

### Throwing people as Weapons

Unfortunately, things get a lot more complicated when you throw flesh in the mix. For the sole reason that creature weights are so widely disproportionate to their sizes (for example, [Kobolds are small monsters that are also 20-25 lbs on average without factoring what they are carrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-kobold/)), it is impossible to toss a cat in the face of an evil overlord (despite how much the jerk deserves it). However, this does not mean you cannot toss people around in general. Enter the humble **[Bull Rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Bull-Rush)**, allowing you to shove a target a minimum 5 feet provided you make a good combat maneuver check. While this won't necessarily be a good way to deal damage to your opponents, with the right feats it's a fantastic way to maintain a good distance between you and them.

After taking at least **[Improved Bull Rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-bull-rush-combat---final/)**, you want to take **[Two-Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/)**, **[Improved Shield Bash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-shield-bash-combat-final/)**, **[Shield Slam](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shield-slam-combat---final/)** and **[Great Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat---final/)** so that if you get surrounded, you can spend one attack to smack the enemy away from you and either book it or throw more fine china at them.

[image: This as a reference]

Whatever you try to do, good luck with it!